# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, c#, json, wcf

I was getting this problem while accessing a REST service delivered by .Net WCF from a javascript node module using whatwg-fetch npm.

Note that the error-message above refers to an unexpected token that seems like whitespace.

As I could not figure out what this was I spent a lot of time considering other possible esoteric issues, like CORS, authentication, mixing up Promises from the fetch API++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause** of this was that the WCF REST service was creating the response via this call:

```
return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(
    json, 
    "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    Encoding.UTF8
);
```

Turns out that when Microsoft implemented the `Encoding.UTF8` encoding they chose to make it prepend the json string with an UTF BOM marker. The result is that the JSON opening brace has three characters in front of it: 
`0xEF`,`0xBB`,`0xBF`. These look like this `ï»¿` when viewed in  ISO-8859-1 or CP1252.

In this case I really should have trusted the error-message, but just the day before I started adding authentication I got reports back from others saying that the REST service was indeed working. I then had started to add the so far missing tests - while also adding authentication. It was at this stage I realized that all tests failed. And - backtracking didn't really help...

As a side-note: It seems that when the code runs in the browser it is more forgiving in regards to the BOM markers. When running the tests in node however it seems to be a lot more picky...

**The solution** was to force BOM marker off for the encoding, like this:

```
// Note, false to avoid BOM marker which breaks some clients not expecting BOM for utf-8
var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(
    json, 
    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    utf8
);
```